# How to move the player by tilting the android phone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to move my player which is just a cube. The movements should just be possible to move forward, back, leftside and rightside. When I'm moving left or right I will still look forward and not rotate. The problem is that i cannot understand how to make my player not passing the walls with physics by using `AccelerometerInput`. I am trying to make some simple 3d game. So if anybody can tell me how this works I am grateful. This is the code:

```
public float speed = 10.0F;

 void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector3 dir = Vector3.zero; 
        dir.x = -Input.acceleration.y;
        dir.z = -Input.acceleration.x;
        if (dir.sqrMagnitude > 1) 
            dir.Normalize();

        dir *= Time.deltaTime; 
        transform.Translate(dir * speed); 
     }
```

I have searched some online and fail to understand what to use. Some says that `Input.GetAxis` ("Horizontal") working, but I cannot understand how my player will move by tilting the android phone.

Answer (score 1):

﻿So generally mobile phones have game orientation such that `z-axis` is depth, `y-axis` is height and `x-axis` is breadth.
As you don't want your object to move on `y-axis`. You just use input for x and z axis.
try this (attach it to your player with rigidbody):

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class playerControl : MonoBehaviour {

    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;

    void Start()    //first Frame
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //physics calc of object
        float moveX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveX, 0.0f, moveZ);

        rb.AddForce(movement * speed);
    }
```

For understanding how horizontal and vertical axis are implemented [check this](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But like I said before i cant get it work because my player does not move with that code. I know that maybe it easy to fix but i cant get it. Should I change something in InputManager (unity)?